# Как заполнить список списков

Tags: python, list, openpyxl

Нужно заполнить список списков данными из Excel файла

```
import openpyxl, os, pprint

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('qwerty.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
tmp = []
for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    for col in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
        tmp[row-1][col-1] = sheet.cell(column=col, row=row).value

pprint.pprint(tmp)
```

в таком виде ошибка IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: На момент первой итерцаии `tmp[row-1][col-1] = sheet.cell(column=col, row=row).value` тут tmp у Вас просто пустой список без единого элемента. Собственно вот и ошибка) Вам надо либо заранее сгенерировать список с пустыми списками, либо добавлять элементы в цикле а не присваивать не существующим элементам значения.

Comment: Я про это подумал, но в голове синтаксис с .append не рисуется)) Не могли бы помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. полностью создать заранее список списков, заполненных дефолтными значениями. Остальную часть можно не менять.

```
tmp = [[None for _ in range(sheet.max_column)] for _ in range(sheet.max_row)]
```

2. Создайте только список со списками, тогда значения надо добавлять.

```
import openpyxl, os, pprint

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('qwerty.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
tmp = [[] for _ in range(sheet.max_row)]
for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    for col in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
        tmp[row-1].appand(sheet.cell(column=col, row=row).value)

pprint.pprint(tmp)
```

Ну и если отойти от этой реализации то можно попробовать создать фрэйм данных, в pandas есть `read_excel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Еще вот такой вариант додумал:

```
import openpyxl, os, pprint

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('qwerty.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
tmp = []
for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    temp2 = []
    for col in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
        temp2.append(sheet.cell(column=col, row=row).value)
    tmp.append(temp2)

pprint.pprint(tmp)
```